# How to create a sortable jquery or similar table with rowspan and colspan

Tags: jquery, html, css, codeigniter, jquery-ui

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdhbE.png

A table like the one provided above, datatables is a bit restricted with the colspan and rowspan, it only works in headers. I've seen an example table in codeignite but it wasn't responsive.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated
Thanks :)

Comment: likely simpler to do it without using a`<table>` as main structure. If each repeating module was a `div` or `li` would be simple to sort

Comment: Thats a pretty complex grid structure, you might have some success using something like bootstrap grid http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid